# How to determine bitwise code value stored in SQL Server from C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to read bitwise value stored into SQL server from C# code.

Assume that following code which stores bitwise values into database.

```
DECLARE @MedCopay VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE @MedDeductible VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE @MedCoins VARCHAR(1);
SET @MedCopay = 'Y';
SET @MedDeductible = 'N';
SET @MedCoins = 'Y';

SELECT CASE
       WHEN @MedCopay = 'Y'
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
   END|CASE
           WHEN @MedDeductible = 'Y'
           THEN 10
           ELSE 0
       END|CASE
               WHEN @MedCoins = 'Y'
               THEN 100
               ELSE 0
           END;
```

Above query will store following value into DB

```
101
```

So question is that how can I write c# code to determine that

```
 101 = MedCopay & MedCoins?
```

Comment: I suggest you to forget about it. SQL is not, generally speaking, the correct tool for this. Use different columns with a boolean type. It will be a lot easier to work with (in particular if you need to search on these values)

Comment: @Steve I agree with your suggestion but at this moment it is not possible to change database structure.

Comment: that is not bitwise representation. `11` in Transact-SQL does not represent binary 11. Binary 11 is the value `3` in Transact-SQL (decimal base).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `enum`?

```
[Flags]
public enum Med {
  Copay = 1,
  Deductable = 2,
  Coins = 4
};
```

and so

```
   // 101
   Console.Write(Convert.ToString((int) (Med.Copay | Med.Coins), 2));
```

reverse:

```
  String source = "101";

  Med parsed = (Med) (Convert.ToInt32(source, 2));
  // Copay, Coins
  Console.Write(parsed);
```

you may want to implement an *extension class* for this:

```
  public static class MedExtensions {
    public static String Represent(this Med value) {
      return Convert.ToString((int) value, 2);
    }
  }
```

And so the test will be

```
  Console.Write((Med.Copay | Med.Coins).Represent());
```